# How to code a good re-render parent call?

Tags: reactjs

render my parent component from a call in its child component. But I don't know how to write it correctly.

The context is: When the page is loaded, the code search the userId in localStorage to download the data of a user to display its information.
A link exists in child component to removed the idUser and got an empty form. The problem is that my parent don't re-render automatically.

```
<Link to="/consultation" onClick={() => {localStorage.removeItem('idUser'); this.props.callBack();}}>here.</Link>
```

-

```
else if(user){contents = [<Message_UserIdentified user callBack={this.forceUpdate()}/>, contentform];}
```

I tried something, but it's not work. Could you help me please ?
I don't know how to parse it (the item "user" and in same time the callBack).

The code write me that it don't find the function forceUpdate().

This is my parents page called "Consultation" (I removed some parts of code to be clearer):

```
import { Message_EmptyUserID, Message_NeedToBeConnected, Message_UserIdentified } from '../component/message_consultation';

const Consultation = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [login] = useState(jwtUtils.checkToken());
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState(false);

    function handleChange(event) {
        setUser({
            ...user,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (login === false || localStorage.getItem("idUser") === null) return;
        axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/users/${localStorage.getItem("idUser")}`, {
            headers: {
                'token': localStorage.getItem('token')
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                setUser(res.data);
                if(res.data !== undefined){
                    setUserId(true);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }, []);

let contents, contentform;

contentform = (
    <div >...
    </div>
);

if (login === false) contents = Message_NeedToBeConnected();
else if (userId === false) contents = contentform;
else if(user){contents = [<Message_UserIdentified user callBack={this.forceUpdate()}/>, contentform];}
return (
    <div className="case card border-secondary mb-3" styles="max-width: 20rem;">
        <div className="card-header">Consultation</div>
        <div className="card-body">
            {contents}
        </div>
    </div>
);
}
export default Consultation;
```

This is my child component called "Message_UserIndentified":

```
const Message_UserIdentified = (user) => {
    return(
        <Alert color="primary" className="alert alert-dismissible alert-info">
            <h4>{user === null || user === undefined ? "" : user.firstname} {user === null || user === undefined ? "" : user.lastname}</h4>
            If you are not {user === null || user === undefined ? "" : user.firstname} and you are <mark>already registered</mark>, find your consultation <Link to="/register" onClick={localStorage.removeItem('idUser')}>here.</Link> <hr/>
            If you are not {user === null || user === undefined ? "" : user.firstname}  and your are <mark>not registered</mark>, add your consultation <Link to="/consultation" onClick={() => {localStorage.removeItem('idUser'); this.props.callBack();}}>here.</Link>
        </Alert>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you mix up the hooks API with the class API. You need to choose one, React doesn't allow to use both in a single component.

React functional components don't have `this` and `this.forceUpdate`. See [the official note](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-forceupdate) on how to force update in a functional component with hooks:

```
const Consultation = () => {
  const [ignored, forceUpdate] = React.useReducer(x => x + 1, 0);

  // ...

  return <Message_UserIdentified user callBack={forceUpdate} />;
};
```

Second, you mustn't call the function when you want to pass it as a callback. When you run `callBack="forceUpdate()"`, the function is executed once and the returned value is passed to the child prop. You need to run `callBack="forceUpdate"` to pass the function itself so that the child component can execute it whenever it wants.

This rule is applicable to class components too, but you should also bind the `forceUpdate` method to the current component:

```
<button onClick={() => this.forceUpdate()}>Demo</button>
// or
<button onClick={this.forceUpdate.bind(this)}>Demo</button>
```

From the architecture point of view, you shouldn't use localStorage to share data between components of the application because localStorage isn't reactive (it doesn't notify when a content changes) so you'll struggle updating all the components manually. You'd rather read'n'write localStorage only in `Consultation` or use a reactive state storage like [Redux](https://redux.js.org) and [MobX](https://mobx.js.org) (in more complex applications). Local storage may be used at the same time: read on an application start and write when something changes.

Comment: Thank you for all information, it's really interesting, I will use Redux now. However my code don't find forceUpdate function :/ ```Line 124:  'forceUpdate' is not defined  no-undef```` Is it because I used hooks ?

Comment: @MalauryBoudon, your components are functional components so they don't have `this.forceUpdate`. You can make your own force update function this way: `const [ignored, forceUpdate] = React.useReducer(x => x + 1, 0);`.